# Cosa significa il detto popolare 'Il mattino ha l’oro in bocca'?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Qualcuno mi potrebbe spiegare che cosa significa il seguente detto popolare:

***Il mattino ha l’oro in bocca?***

Comment: Basta consultare un qualsiasi dizionario : http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/mattino/ - http://dettieproverbi.it/proverbi/italia/il-mattino-ha-loro-in-bocca/

Comment: Grazie, non conoscevo questo sito.

Comment: Forse sarebbe più interessante chiedere da dove viene questo modo di dire, e se ce ne sono altri di analoghi.

Comment: Qualcuno può scrivere la risposta?

Comment: Qui https://it.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070316141356AATVvu5 ho trovato una risposta, ma non saprei confermarla

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Il significato del proverbio ***"Il mattino ha l'oro in bocca"***, come riportato dal [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/mattino/), è il seguente:

> il m. ha l’oro in bocca, o le ore del m. hanno l’oro in bocca, sono
>   quelle in cui il lavoro o lo studio o altra attività rendono meglio.

Essendo le ore del mattino quelle in cui una persona solitamente è più riposata e lucida, tutte le cose che si fanno hanno un maggior rendimento.

Ho trovato [alcuni cenni](http://forum.corriere.it/scioglilingua/11-07-2009/e_buonanotte_sia-1306836.html) alle caratteristiche di questo detto:

> Per "L'oro in bocca", ma più propriamente "Il mattino ha l'oro in
>   bocca" c'è da dire che quando uno stesso proverbio o modo di dire si
>   ritrova in diverse lingue è molto probabile che sia nato autonomamente
>   in ciascuna di esse ma la forma più antica è generalmente la più
>   espressivamente efficace. In questo caso è una forma idiomatica
>   tedesca: Die Morgenstunde hat Gold im Munde, la cui traduzione è:
>   "l'ora del mattino ha l'oro in bocca". Il significato o valenza di
>   tale detto può ricondursi o alla qualità del tempo del mattino che per
>   molti detti popolari sembra rivesta qualcosa di speciale (molte
>   culture dell'Estremo oriente confermano che al levar del sole
>   l'atmosfera è più ricca di energie) o è allusiva al tempo magico
>   dell'infanzia per cui ad ogni bimbo si aprono infinite possibilità.

Inoltre da [Cotidie legere 3a ediz. pagina 64 numero 15](http://www.latin.it/versione/2406)

> Est in proverbio: "Auorora aurum in ore habet"; ideo homines horis
>   matutinis cum sollertia ad negotia animum intendunt, quia matutino
>   tempore magnas...

che significa all'incirca:

> È (scritto) in un proverbio: "L'aurora (meglio il mattino) ha l'oro in
>   bocca": perciò gli uomini attivi nelle ore mattutine rivolgono con
>   solerzia la loro mente agli affari, poichè di mattina ottengono
>   dall'operosità grandi e mirabili vantaggi

Comment: Dovrebbe essere “aurora” e non “auorora”, ma in ogni caso è una citazione interessante, perché fa parte delle paretimologie che, più o meno scherzosamente, cercano il senso di una parola nella sua origine apparente, come quella per Vienna: “Vindobona, quia dat vinum bonum”. Spesso, per far tornare i conti, erano *a contrario*: “Canis a non canendo” (“[Si chiama] cane perché non canta”) etc.

Answer (score 2):

Si rifà all'alchimia perché l'oro filosofale (la rugiada degli adepti) è molto più facile da reperire al mattino.
Anche il proverbio " ha addosso l'argento vivo " deriva da questa antica scienza.
[image]

Comment: Interessante, se è vero. Hai qualche fonte?

Comment: Benvenuta su Italian.SE!